# Azure Devops Permission Service Connection to specific Release Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-aks

I have been trying to limit a kubernetes service connection that has admin priviledges to one specific release pipeline but it seems that that the security to limit service connections only applies to build pipelines. Does anyone know if it is possible to implement with Release Pipelines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure Devops Permission Service Connection to specific Release Pipeline

According to the document we could to know [Service connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#manage-a-service-connection):

The service connection security is divided into three categories in the service connections new UI:

- User permissions
- Pipeline permissions
- Project permissions

When your pipeline uses the classic UI mode, you could use `User permissions` to control who can create, view, use and manage the service connection with user permissions. We have four roles i.e. `Creator`, `Reader`, `User` and `Administrator` roles to manage each of these actions.

So, we could add a user/group with User/Administrator permissions on that page.

If your pipeline is YAML mode, you could use the `Pipeline permissions`, Pipeline permissions control which YAML pipelines are authorized to use this service connection. This is interlinked with 'Allow pipeline access' checkbox you find in service connection creation dialogue.

Besides, since [Multi-stage YAML pipelines (for CI and CD)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/whats-new-with-azure-pipelines/), We include the release in our YAML pipeline. So this is also why you did not see a separate Release Pipeline permissions for service connection.

So, we do not need implement Service Connection Permission for Release Pipelines.